# How can I get a reference to the item being loaded from SP.ClientRequest object passed to the callback for executeQueryAsync?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I am trying to load a list that exists in multiple subsites in a given site collection.  as I enumerate for-each web in the site collection I am loading a particular list by Title.

I am having trouble getting a context to the list being loaded in the callback, however I can see it in the f12 developer tools in the browser.

Can someone give us more info on SP.ClientRequest?

Here is some code:

```
    // other code was redacted
    onSummaryListLoad : function (sender, args) { 
        // want to get a reference to 'summarylist' here from 'sender'  
    },
    onLoadSubWebs : function (sender, args) {
        //function () {  
            console.log('loaded subwebs successfully');   

            var webs = this.subWebs.getEnumerator();
            while (webs.moveNext()) {
                var thisWeb = webs.get_current();
                console.log(thisWeb.get_title());
                this.summarylist = thisWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Project Summary');
                context.load(this.summarylist, "DefaultDisplayFormUrl");
                context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSummaryListLoad), Function.createDelegate(this, this.APICallFailed)); 
            }
    // other code was redacted
```

Image from the Browser Tools:

[image]

Thank!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question (other context, but with executeQueryAsync).
In my case it was a startWorkflow function where I needed the $15_0 from

```
var startWFReq = wfsManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflow(...)
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
//success function
   function (sender, args) {
       //in this case startWFReq equals sender.$15_0["18"]
       console.log(startWFReq);
   },
// fail function
   function(sender, args){

   }
```

So in your case I should try to use this:

```
onSummaryListLoad : function (sender, args) { 
    // want to get a reference to 'summarylist' here from 'sender'  
    //reference to summarylist:
    this.summarylist
},
onLoadSubWebs : function (sender, args) {
    //function () {  
        console.log('loaded subwebs successfully');   

        var webs = this.subWebs.getEnumerator();
        while (webs.moveNext()) {
            var thisWeb = webs.get_current();
            console.log(thisWeb.get_title());
            this.summarylist = thisWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Project Summary');
            context.load(this.summarylist, "DefaultDisplayFormUrl");
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSummaryListLoad), Function.createDelegate(this, this.APICallFailed)); 
        }
```

Allthough I doubt that the scope will be ok. 
So I should take a look here: 
http://blog.mannsoftware.com/?p=353
And make something like this

```
createDelegate(equal_to_the_web_id_inside_the_loop, this.onSummaryListLoad)
```